# Unable to start/debug program

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I recently installed Visual Studio 2010 to help me with some exercises for class.
It all worked great in school but when I got home and tried to run and debug the second program I got this error:

> Unable to start ...\Kapitel_1\Debug\Kapitel_1.exe
>
> This application has failed to start because the application configuration is incorrect. Review the manifest file for possible errors. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem. For more details, please see the application event log.

How can this be solved?

Answer (score 0):

This message generally means that the machine on which you built the application did not have the same redistributables than the system where you run the application.

Redistributables are sets of DLLs needed for your application to run properly.

In your case, I noticed that you are trying to run a debug build. That might just be the problem: you cannot run an application or use a DLL that has been built in debug configuration on a system with no debugger installed. Installing Visual Studio (ideally the same version your school has) should do the trick. You could also rebuild your application in Release configuration to avoid having to install a debugger on the running system.

Another case where this error message might be displayed is if you just installed a new Visual Studio update on the system that built the application and not on the system where you are trying to run it. In that case, you would need to update your system with the latest set of redistributables from Microsoft (at time of writing, [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/download/search.aspx?q=redistributable) was a good place to look for that).