# VS 2010: Unable to start Application

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2010

I have vb.net application and working from last 1 years I never faced issue to start application from VS 2010. but Last day I faced issue that unable to start application because the application configuration is incorrect. Details Exception image as below.

[image]

Already [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8055561/unable-to-start-debug-program) post related this exist. But not found any answer. After ReBulild Solution my application working fine and above error not coming. But I want know reason behind above Error.

Any help or answer for above error would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I added an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12766146/221111) to the [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8055561/unable-to-start-debug-program) you linked to which should help you understand what this message means.